# Дергается к верху сайт после загрузки анимации

Tags: javascript, css

[Ссылка на сайт!](http://sarpedon.dtraduga.vh55.hosterby.com/index.html)
Для анимации использовалась библиотека animation.css 
Если открыть на мобиле, то при загрузке очередного блока с анимацией сайт дергается к верху и проскакивает горизонтальная прокрутка.
При попытке скрыть горизонтальную прокрутку анимация перестает работать.
Про дерганье вообще не понимаю из-за чего может быть?

Comment: Без примеров совершенно невозможно понять о чем идет речь.

Comment: Простите. Добавил линк в начале вопроса.

Comment: overflow-x: hidden для body. Скорее всего - это из-за горизонтального скролла.

Comment: так не помогает к сожалению, я пробовал (

Comment: может есть еще какие-нибудь предложения у кого-нибудь?